# How to specify dns for go get command

Tags: go, dns, go-modules

I have a dependency which is published in company's GitLab and is only discoverable with domain name from a certain dns server. The `go get` command is failing to fetch such dependency on my local environment like this:

```
go get our-domain.com/group/library@v0.1.0                                            
go: our-domain.com/group/library@v0.1.0: verifying go.mod: our-domain.com/group/library@v0.1.0/go.mod: reading https://sum.golang.org/lookup/our-domain.com/group/library@v0.1.0: 410 Gone
        server response: not found: our-domain.com/group/library@v0.1.0: unrecognized import path "our-domain.com/group/library": https fetch: Get "https://our-domain.com/group/library?go-get=1": dial tcp: lookup our-domain.com on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host
```

It works if I'm building inside docker with adding dns to `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{ "dns": ["1.2.3.4"] }
```

How to do it for getting dependency locally?
Running on MacOs with go1.13

I tried to add DNS address to the Network settings but `go get` still doesn't use it.

Comment: Note that it can also be helpful to have your own company internal Go modules proxy. This would additionally allow you to work/build even if for some reason some or all of your external dependencies are (temporarily) not available. For example: https://github.com/gomods/athens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try set `GOPRIVATE=our-domain.com`.

```
go env -w GOPRIVATE=our-domain.com
```

Otherwise the command tries to resolve the name using the Go proxy and checksum db.